# How to import cv2 in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, numpy

I'm using Windows, and I'm trying to install package cv2 for python3.

I did a `pip3 install opencv-python` and it reports successful:

[image: opencv-python3 is installed]

But when I do the `import cv2` from python3, it's not found and I get weird errors:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Full Stop, you're trying to do something impossible. Python 2.7 is the ONLY supported python version for cv 2.x series. Read the section: "Supported Python versions: here: pypi.org/project/opencv-python Three workarounds. 1: 
 Just use python2.7 and regular pip, so you can use cv2.  2: Install cv2 from source code so it autodetects your system and from source does the right thing.  Finally 3: pitch in and jump on the openCV github and help them make CV2 binary packages in the repos for python3.

Comment: Of course you may install opencv on python3, this issue is due to missing operating system packages (opencv dependencies, such as gcc) search on google how to install them base on your operating system. I recommend you to use some linux distros, i prefer (and always recommend) Centos-7 it works perfectly. 

https://gist.github.com/alundiak/4c0de8d657daa872f31e1df5f9056df8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to create a virtual env. first and then do pip install , everything will work fine

Answer (score 91):

Your screenshot shows you doing a `pip install` from the python terminal which is wrong.  Do that outside the python terminal.  Also the package I believe you want is:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

Since you're running on Windows, I might look at the official install manual: https://breakthrough.github.io/Installing-OpenCV

opencv2 is ONLY compatible with Python3 if you do so by compiling the source code.  See the section under opencv supported python versions: https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python

Comment: Better make it `pip3 install opencv-python`. Sometimes multiple versions of python is available on a system and the default usually is python 2.7.

Comment: well, it shows requirements are already satisfied when I try doing pip install on cmd

Comment: after this, I can import opencv, but import cv2 fails. Is cv2 no more a module?

Comment: @deadcode: this is really strange... openCV is imported via `import cv2` since years now, probably since version 2.0 was introduced in 2009. Maybe you are living up to your name, using the "dead" openCV 1.0? Which python and openCV versions are you using? (check `python --version` in shell and for cv it usually is `print(cv2.__version__)` so maybe try `opencv.__version__`)

Comment: I am dead and also a newbie. I can import cv2 from python in terminal which uses 2.7 by default, and cv2 version is 2.4.9.1. But when I open python3, I can only import opencv and that opencv has no attribute version. Maybe now I realise the point of virtualenvs

Comment: As of 2021, `pip install opencv-python` IS [compatible with Python 3](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/), so this answer should be edited to clarify that.

Answer (score 7):

Make a virtual enviroment using python3

```
virtualenv env_name --python="python3"
```

and run the following command

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

Answer (score 7):

There is a problem with pylint, which I do not completely understood yet.

You can just import OpenCV with:
`from cv2 import cv2`

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Please check your python version. Mine is 3.7.3 on a Mac `macOS Catalina Version 10.15.7`.
If you are using Jupyter notebook,
`pip3 install opencv-python`
is enough.
In your notebook menu click on Kernel and hit restart. Please see the image I included.
[Kernel>Restart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gj7S9.png)
Then run your code again. In my case that solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

anaconda prompt -->`pip install opencv-python`

Answer (score 1):

well, there was 2 issues:
1.instead of pip, pip3 should be used.
2.its better to use virtual env. because i have had multiple python version installed

Answer (score 0):

First check your python version, for example 3.10 then you can run this command to check opencv status

```
python3.10 -m pip show opencv-python
```

If not installed then install like this,

```
python3.10 -m pip install opencv-python
```

Make sure your IDE is using the correct version of Python

For example, In VSCode, you can press *CTRL + Shift + P* or *(⌘ + Shift + P on Mac)* to open the command palette.

Then type "Python select interpreter" in the field and select correct version of python.

Answer (score 0):

Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.3.1 -> 23.3.2
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35488595)

Answer (score -1):

Use '!' before the pip:

```
! pip install opencv-python
```

Comment: This is for a Jupyter notebook cell