# I can't import cv2,vlc and numpy python pycharm

Tags: python, vlc, opencv

I can't import modules in pycharm. When I wanted to import cv2 for example, I get this error:

Please can somebody help me. I tried all other solutions but they did not help

Comment: You haven't attached the error you got. Make sure that you have installed opencv before trying to import it (isn't part of the standard installation of python/pycharm)

Comment: Also try adding your virtual environment to PyCharm project settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the image you uploaded it seems like you are using a virtual environment. If that was intended make sure you have installed opencv in your environment. Otherwise you can change the interpreter for the project by going to:

"File" --> "Settings" --> "Project: project_name" --> "Project Interpreter"

From there you can change or add an interpreter and see what packages are attached to the interpreter. See example below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should write this in terminal or cmd and than try:

pip install opencv-python

here is more info: 
[How to import cv2 in python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46610689/how-to-import-cv2-in-python3)