# cv2 videoCapture has no attribute

Tags: python, opencv

```py
import cv2

import sys


cpt=0

vidStream=cv2.videoCapture(0)
while True:
    ret,frame=vidStream.read()

    cv2.imshow("test frame",frame)
    cv2.imwrite(r"C:\Users\Abhishek\PycharmProjects\images\0\image%04i.jpg"%cpt,frame)
    cpt +=1

    if cv2.waitKey(10)==ord('q'):
        break
```

anyone please help me fix the error
I'm getting an error which says"module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'videoCapture'"and "unable to import cv2"

Comment: Read:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46610689/how-to-import-cv2-in-python3

Answer (score 3):

1)It's not cv2.videoCapture() but try instead cv2.VideoCapture().

```
Python 2.7.18rc1 (default, Apr  7 2020, 12:05:55) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>> vid = cv2.videoCapture(0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'videoCapture'
>>> vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0) #like that it works fine.
>>>
```

Try to install **opencv** with the command `pip install opencv-python`or `pip install opencv-contrib-python`, and check if you still get the  "unable to import cv2" error

Answer (score 1):

Please install

`pip install opencv-python` and
`pip install opencv-contrib-python` and then run below code....

```
import cv2
import sys
cpt=0
vidStream=cv2.videoCapture(0)
while True:
    ret,frame=vidStream.read()
    cv2.imshow("test frame",frame)
    cv2.imwrite(r"C:\Users\Abhishek\PycharmProjects\images\0\image%04i.jpg"%cpt,frame)
    cpt +=1
    if cv2.waitKey(10)==ord('q'):
        break
```

Comment: `pip install opencv-contrib-python` is finally what fixed my problem. Thank you!