# Import Error on PyCharm For cv2 and NumPy

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm, importerror

I worked on a project on PyCharm a few years ago (which worked fine). However now when I run the first two lines of the program:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def getContours(img_orig):
    [Rest of Function]
.
.
.
```

I am getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[PATH]", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

What is strange is the exact same code was working flawlessly a few years ago. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the packages but there's no difference. What could be going on here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46610689/how-to-import-cv2-in-python3

Answer (score 0):

You may be re-installing un-installing packages in a different enviorment then what pycharm is using for running it.

Try comparing pycharm's `PYTHONPATH` variable and `pip --version` 's output.

cv2 is generally provided by the opencv package.